# Need help with Solidworks

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solidworks, technical-drawing

Would I be allowed to ask which Solidworks feature I should use to make the recessed bit (circled in red) of the thing in the diagram below? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It depends on the order in which you are creating features on the drawing... You could equally make this with three extrudes, or one extrude and two cuts, or two extrudes and a cut... What have you done so far?

Comment: I would recommend one extrude and two cuts, based on the variable dimension C

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I've done a boss extrude where I extruded the original sketch I made of the outline of the part and the two holes and I've cut extruded the 19 mm recessions.

Comment: Ok. See the 12mm dimension? In the cut dialogue, select "offset" as the start condition, and type in 12mm for your cut to start offset from the sketch plane.

Comment: Or create a reference plane that is 12mm away from that face, and make the sketch for your cut on that plane.

Comment: I could be wrong here, but it is my understanding that you should use the hole tool as opposed making the circle in the outline then extruding.  @JonathanRSwift care to chime in as I am a relative neophyte on the mechanical side of 3D modelling.

Comment: Not especially relevant here - the benefit of using hole wizard is when you have multiple instances of a similar hole (it effectively is a sketch driven pattern), it's more than a through hole (e.g. counterbored), or there is additional data such as a thread that you want to appear on the auto-generated hole callout when making a drawing. None of the above apply to this example, but, there isn't a significant downside to using it anyway besides an extra feature in the tree.